# Minesweeper: Python error. AttributeError: type object has no attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes

I am quite new to coding and is having trouble with accessing the attributes of objects inside of another object.
I have tried explicitly creating a method for returning the attribut to no awail. i cant seem to find a good explination online.

The code that i am working on have the ultimate goal of simulating a game of minesweeper. To do this i have created a class named minefield.

```
class Minefield:
    def __init__(self, height, width, bombs):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.bombs = bombs
        self.flagged_amount = 0
        self.minefield = []
        self.setup_minefield()

    def setup_minefield(self):  # setup for the minefield
        for x in range(self.height):
            self.minefield.append([])
            for y in range(self.width):
                self.minefield[x].append(Cell)
```

As well as a class named Cell

```
class Cell:
   def __init__(self):  # setup for new cell
        self.revealed = False
        self.bomb = False
        self.flag = False
        self.nearby_bombs = 0
```

Now, the issue that im having is that when i try to access an attribute of a cell in the minefield i get the error:  AttributeError: type object 'Cell' has no attribute 'flag'

The code that im trying to run right now (resulting in the error) using theese classes is quite simple (see below) but i will need to use these attributes for many planned functions later in the program.

```
my_minefield = Minefield(5, 5, 2)
    if my_minefield.minefield[1][1].flag:
        print ("yay")
```

I am not sure why this isnt working and would greatly appreciate any help in understanding the issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
self.minefield[x].append(Cell)
```

You're appending the `Cell` class, not an instance of it. You have to instanciate the class by calling it:

```
self.minefield[x].append(Cell())
```